# Does OS X not support epoll function?

Tags: macos, epoll, kqueue

I'm learning to use epoll function. 
But my OS X, Mountain Lion doesn't have a header file, sys/epoll.h.

I'd like to use epoll function on OS X. How Can I use epoll function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't support epoll, but it does support [kqueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/kqueue.2.html) which is very similar.

Comment: updated link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/kqueue.2.html

Answer (score 0):

on Mac OSX use kqueue instead of epoll.
Do something like this in your java code.

```
 final boolean isMac = 

  System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("mac");

    // Configure the server.
    // See https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup;
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup;

    if (isMac) {
        bossGroup = new io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup();
        workerGroup = new io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup(5);
    } else {
        bossGroup =  new io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup();
        workerGroup = new io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup(5);
    }
```

Ensure that you have added io.netty on pom.xml